# How to define obj c target with a header file so other targets can implement it in SPM? (error: target 'Foo' referenced in product 'Foo' is empty)

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, xcode, swift-package-manager

I am using SPM in a project and want to define a target that has just an objc header. So it look like this:

> Sources/Foo/include/MyHeader.h

But when generating a project, spm complains `error: target 'Foo' referenced in product 'Foo' is empty`. This complain goes away if I add a dummy `.m` file.

> Sources/Foo/include/MyHeader.h
> Sources/Foo/MyHeader.m

```
#import "MyHeader.h"
@import Foundation;

int _keep;
```

Referenced as:

```
.target(
  name: "Foo",
  dependencies: [],
  path: "Sources/Foo"
)
```

How do I define an obj c target with just a header file so other targets can implement it?

Comment: As far as I know, there needs to be a dummy `.m` file